# SVG isn't loading with Angular

Tags: css, angularjs, svg, icons, mean

I'm building a MEAN app and want to quickly use some icons. I settled with linearicons (https://linearicons.com/free). For a quick set up, you just copy a cdn into your HTML head and then drop the desired SVG tag wherever you want. On Codepen it works without any issue, but it isn't working on localhost. I suspect it has something to do with Angular.

When I inspect the code with chrome I can see that the SVG is being added. I can even hover over the spot and see it highlight, but the actual lines aren't shown. I checked in other browsers and the same issue remains.

Edit 1: I just wrote a simple app with node and express and I had no trouble dropping in the SVGs. So it appears that Angular is blocking the SVG.

```
Edit 2: http://codepen.io/Perxis/pen/wazLXe
```

Edit 3: Out of nowhere they're working. I am fairly certain I changed nothing, but now they work. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Are there definitely no js libraries being used that are added into the codepen 's settings but not your site's head?

Comment: I just created a simple node express app and I can drop in the icons without any problem. So it seems that Angular is blocking the SVG somehow.

Comment: Post the codepen link up, it might be helpful. I've not used this icon thing before, but I'd suggest also posting the angular code you're referencing too

Comment: I completely dropped the code from the codepen into my HTML. I tried multiple HTML pages. I don't think submitting my HTML would be very helpful. There is quite a bit.

Comment: Could it be that you are striking this problem?: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8934

Comment: It looks like it... I commented out <base href='/'> and all my styling went away, but I did have the SVG icon. Not sure what to do from here.